# Event booking for multiple guests

Tags: civievent

If a client is trying to book an event for multiple guests, is that possible to book (and pay online) without having to book himself?  It is very common for a PA to book for bosses, or a junior staff to book for senior staff.  The PA and the junior staff do not need to book the event for himself.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, One can register for events on behalf using backend form or front end form.

Backend:

Navigate to Events >> Register Events Participants. Select Contact and Event to register.
[image]

Front End:

Visit online page by navigating to Events >> Manage Events. Click on Event links against the event you want to register and then click on Registration(live).  If you are logged in than online form will pre populate with your details, to register other contact click on the link (Not Pradeep, or want to register a different person?) as shown in below image.
[image]

Here you will get 2 options

1. To select Contact from auto select field. (if user have permission to view contacts in system)
2. Create registration for new contact. In this case if CiviCRM finds duplicate match of this contact (using rule defined in dedupe rule) than it will update the existing contact in CiviCRM.